# Xcode iPhone App - NSDate timeIntervalSinceDate problem - Unknown Cause - Please help!

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsdate, nstimeinterval

From viewcontroller.m file

```
-(void) hitButton
{
    current = [NSDate date];

    interval = [current timeIntervalSinceDate:last];

    rate = 60 / (double)interval;
    last = current;

    NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d bpm",rate];
    [btnout setTitle:output forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    last = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    current = [[NSDate alloc] init];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

From Viewcontroller header file

```
@interface RateAnalyserViewController : UIViewController {

double interval;
int rate;
NSDate *current;
NSDate *last;

    IBOutlet UIButton *btnhit;
    IBOutlet UIButton *btnout;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *btnhit;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *btnout;

-(IBAction) hitButton;

@end
```

Hi,
I'm trying to make a simple app that displays the rate in BPM that someone presses a button.

For some reason the app works fine on the first press but crashes the second time. No exception or any info is given as to why. I've used NSLogs to verify the hitButton method is called the second time and established that the program crashes @ current = [NSDate date].

Any help would be appreciated. Sorry if I've missed anything out. Am new to OO languages.

Thanks, Jon

Answer (score 0):

Jon, the issue is the "current" ivar is autoreleased so the next time the run loop spins, it's gone (works the first time cause you alloc-init'ed it which creates an object with a retain count of 1 that isn't autoreleased). Change the line in hitButton to this and you'll be good to go:

```
last = [current retain];
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks very much for the response. That was indeed the problem! Cheers, Jon